# system.invalidoperationexception: Fill: selectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized

Tags: visual-studio, ms-access, database-connection

I'm working on connecting the MS Access database in Visual basic. Unfortunately, I cannot link the records from my data base into visual basic.

My database is located at C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\GUI references\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\bin\Debug

Database name is **smsenabler.mdb**

Table to be connected is **ProfessorListTable**

The table contains fields of

> ID | LastName | FirstName | MI  | Department | Year Employed

My codes on my form are shown below:

```
    Imports System.Data.OleDb

Public Class ProfessorList
    Dim con As OleDbConnection

    Private Sub Label1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub ProfessorList_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Try
            Dim con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection
            con.ConnectionString = "Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source = ..\smsenabler.mdb"
            con.Open()

            showRecords()
            con.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
    Public Sub showRecords()
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        ds.Tables.Add(dt)

        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from ProfessorListTable", con)
        da.Fill(dt)

        Dim myRow As DataRow

        For Each myRow In dt.Rows
            ListView1.Items.Add(myRow.Item(0))
            ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(myRow.Item(1))
            ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(myRow.Item(2))
            ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(myRow.Item(3))
            ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(myRow.Item(4))
            ListView1.Items(ListView1.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add(myRow.Item(5))
        Next

    End Sub
```

> ERROR MESSAGE

**system.invalidoperationexception: Fill: selectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized. At System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.GetConnection3(DbDataAdapter adapter,IDbCommand command String method) at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables,Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable) at THESIS_GUI.ProfessorList.ProfessorList_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\GUI references\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\ProfessorList.vb:line17**

**LINE 17**

> showRecords()

It gives me an output with no records at all.It only shows a GUI with a field written on it. Thank you ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One suggestion is to make sure your connection ('con') is available for all subroutines. I have used global variables before to prevent the need for opening and closing the connection (which would lead to problems in the old days).  We both do a similar approach, but here is some code I have stripped bare (removed error traps, debug aids, etc.):

```
Global cnLocalData  As ADODB.Connection
Public Sub Get_Connection()
    Set cnLocalData = New ADODB.Connection
    With cnLocalData
        .Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
        .Properties("Data Source") = "C:\data\SomeDB.mdb"
        .Open
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

you are disconnected to the server, you must open you connection in the `showRecords` method.

This error error appear when you want to execute a command with the closed connection.